# C# Wix Execute CA After Install

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

Hi i'm trying to execute a custom action after the installation is finished, but
only execute when uninstall the program.

i try this:

```
new ManagedAction(CustomActions.SayHi, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallFinalize, Condition.Installed)
```

CA:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult a(Session session)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hola");
  return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

thanks

Comment: what's your wixsharp version

Comment: Hi, it is 1.14.8

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, a `Condition.Installed` will be `true` exactly when the application is already installed. *During* the install it will be set to false. Try to replace `Condition.Installed` with a `Condition.NOT_Installed`. Also check this [sample](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/a97b51e58d8713b84eb3be804dc1f9cc6748daa0/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/GAC/setup_manual_registration.cs) from wix# distribution.